# Populate values in angular material auto-complete not working

Tags: typescript, angular9

I have added angular material auto complete select to my form.
Problem is values don't get populate in the dropdown.

Below is the code snippet i am using.

1. I have considered an string array which has objects with two property. eg: Id and CityName
2. In angular material auto-complete, i bind them by looping this array but no values are binded.

Html Markup

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="city">City</label>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width d-block">
              <input
                type="text"
                [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                matInput
                placeholder="Select city"
                class="form-control border"
              />
              <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options">
                  {{ option.name }}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
```

.ts code

```
export class CustomerEditComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  options: CityMaster[];
  selectedOption: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.options = [
      { id: 1, cityName: "Mumbai" },
      { id: 2, cityName: "Delhi" },
      { id: 3, cityName: "Banglore" },
      { id: 4, cityName: "Lucknow" }
    ];
  }
}
```

Do i necessarily have to use Observable to bind values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property in options is cityName and the one binded in html is name.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width d-block">
      <input type="text" [matAutocomplete]="auto" matInput placeholder="Select city" class="form-control border" />
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.id">
          {{ option.cityName }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```